# Sample from vector and keep zero frequencies

Tags: r

I want to sample with replacement from a vector. For example:

```
set.seed(11)
x = as.data.frame(table(sample(c("one", "two", "three"), 5, replace = T, prob = c(0.05, 0.45, 0.5))))
```

returns:

```
x

Var1 Freq
1 three    4
2   two    1
```

Is there a way to get a data frame which would contain "one" freq as well, where value would be 0:

```
Var1 Freq

1 three    4
2   two    1
3   one    0
```

Comment: Not a big deal, you have an extra ")" at the end of line 2 of your code. It's too small of an edit for me to be allowed to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a factor and sample on that :

```
f_sa <-  factor(c("one", "two", "three"))
x <- as.data.frame(table(sample(f_sa, 5, replace = T, prob = c(0.05, 0.45, 0.5))))

x
#    Var1 Freq
# 1   one    0
# 2 three    4
# 3   two    1
```

*If you want it to be sorted by frequency instead of level:*

```
x[order(x$Freq, decreasing=T),]

#   Var1 Freq
#2 three    4
#3   two    1
#1   one    0
```